# Python numpy.divmod and integer representation

Tags: python, numpy, internal-representation, divmod

I was trying to use `numpy.divmod` with very large integers and I noticed a strange behaviour. At around `2**63 ~ 1e19` (which should be the limit for the usual memory representation of `int` in python 3.5+), this happens:

```
from numpy import divmod

test = 10**6
for i in range(15,25):
  x = 10**i
  print(i, divmod(x, test))

15 (1000000000, 0)
16 (10000000000, 0)
17 (100000000000, 0)
18 (1000000000000, 0)
19 (10000000000000.0, 0.0)
20 ((100000000000000, 0), None)
21 ((1000000000000000, 0), None)
22 ((10000000000000000, 0), None)
23 ((100000000000000000, 0), None)
24 ((1000000000000000000, 0), None)
```

Somehow, the quotient and remainder works fine till `2**63`, then there's something different.

My guess is that the `int` representation is "vectorized" (i.e. as `BigInt` in Scala, as a little endian `Seq` of `Long`). But then, I'd expect, as a result of `divmod(array, test)`, a pair of arrays: the array of quotients and the array of remainders.

I have no clue about this feature. It does not happen with the built-in divmod (everything works as expected)

Why does this happen? Does it have something to do with `int` internal representation?

Details: numpy version 1.13.1, python 3.6

Comment: I guess you should just file a [bug report](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues). It's not clear to me what your question is (aside from showcasing a probably buggy behavior).

Comment: I added a more precise question. It might be a bug, but I wonder if there's a rational (and coherent) explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `np.divmod` will convert the arguments to arrays and what happens is really easy:

```
>>> np.array(10**19)
array(10000000000000000000, dtype=uint64)
>>> np.array(10**20)
array(100000000000000000000, dtype=object)
```

You will get an `object` array for `10**i` with `i > 19`, in the other cases it will be a "real NumPy array".

And, indeed, it seems like `object` arrays behave strangely with `np.divmod`:

```
>>> np.divmod(np.array(10**5, dtype=object), 10)   # smaller value but object array
((10000, 0), None)
```

I guess in this case the normal **Python** built-in [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#divmod) calculates the first returned element and all remaining items are filled with `None` because it delegated to Pythons function.

Note that `object` arrays often behave differently than native dtype arrays. They are a lot slower and often delegate to Python functions (which is often the reason for different results).

Comment: This is it! I was not expecting the cast to "object". They are slower indeed, infact divmod is 10x faster than np.divmod for those numbers (I guess the object casting adds overhead). Thank you!